# Merge down two cells in a column using CarlosAg ExcelXMLWriter

Tags: excel

I am using CarlosAg ExcelXMLWriter. I am able to use some of the features as shown in the sample provided in the site. But I am unable to merge two or more cells in a column.
Following works:

```
WorksheetCell cell = row.Cells.Add("Header 3");
cell.MergeAcross = 1;            // Merge two cells together
cell.StyleID = "HeaderStyle";
```

But this does not:

```
WorksheetCell cell = row.Cells.Add("Header 3");
cell.MergeDown = 2;            // Merge two cells together down
cell.StyleID = "HeaderStyle";
```

Has anyone experienced the same? Help Please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I also encountered the same issue which took me time analyze and research. What I did was, change this line first to

*cell.MergeDown = 1;*

run and extract the file. Once successful, try to put it back to

*cell.MergeDown = 2;*

This worked fine for me.